# How to interpret this contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, magnetometer

I am working on a project on *indoor localization using Sensors* and have prepared a dataset that looks like this:

```
1   0   0   30.263302
2   0   1   30.154142
3   0   2   30.159311
4   1   0   29.978758
5   1   1   29.802172
6   1   2   29.716825
7   2   0   29.671733
8   2   1   29.642293
9   2   2   29.573582
```

The above data is the mean values of sensor readings that I collected from an app. The second two columns are just coordinates (such as 0,0 0,1 0,2....2,2) and the last column is the average of the sensor data.

I have created a plot but I cannot understand how to make sense of it. So can any one help me understand whats going on in the below image?

[image: Contour image]

Comment: It would be nice to know how did you create that plot, or at least what's on the axes.

Comment: I created a plot using 3DField software.

Comment: You get a contour plot with its accompanying legend. On the contour lines, normalized values (0 to 2) are used instead of min to max of raw values. Contour lines are colored from lightest to darkest representing the values 0 to 2, and they are indicated by the scale-bar legend to the right of the plot.

Comment: A contour plot is not a great way to view this data -- most of the structures that catch the eye here are entirely from the algorithm and have nothing to do with the data. Try instead a scatter plot where the colors of the points indicate their values; or a 2D bar plot; etc: ie, something where you can see a graphical representation of the values of the individual points.

Comment: Was the given answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create a similar plot from data like yours. Note that you have values around 30, while your example plot has values in the range 0.1 - 2.1.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

M, N = 24, 15
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.repeat(np.arange(M), N),
                   'Y': np.tile(np.arange(N), M),
                   'Val': 30 + np.random.normal(size=(M, N)).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1).ravel() / 2})
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
scat = ax1.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], c=df['Val'], cmap='Spectral')
plt.colorbar(scat, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('just the values')

xs = df['X'].to_numpy().reshape(M, N)
ys = df['Y'].to_numpy().reshape(M, N)
vals = df['Val'].to_numpy().reshape(M, N)

contours = ax2.contour(xs, ys, vals, cmap='Spectral')
ax2.clabel(contours, inline=1, fmt='%.1f', fontsize=10)
plt.colorbar(contours, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('isolines')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

The demo data are like:

```py
   X  Y        Val
0  0  0  30.505696
1  0  1  30.617889
2  0  2  30.585834
3  0  3  31.455314
4  0  4  30.897253
```

So, for each xy grid point there is a measurement.  The scatter plot shows a dot for each measurement with its color indicating its value.

`ax.contour()` creates [contour lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) (or isolines) connecting all spots where the measurement is estimated to have the same value. `ax.clabel()` adds text labels to show the value. In this case the isolines and text have the same color as the scatter plot, to better see the correspondence. Choosing fixed colors instead would generate a plot similar to the example.

Apart from `ax.contour()` which needs x and y to lie on a grid, there is also `ax.tricontour()` where x and y can be located more freely.